# Caption tails trailing below image in figcaption position absolute

Tags: html, css, position, figure

I am trying to position a caption over the bottom part of an image using `position absolute` and `bottom 0` which it is doing, but the tails of the g and the y letters area dangling down below the edge of the image. Is this expected behavious and do I just have to adjust my positioning of the caption up a bit?

Here's the code:

```css
.article-image,
figure {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}

figure {
  margin-block-start: 0em;
  margin-block-end: 0em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
}

cite {
  font-size: 0.85em;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img class="aside-image" src="images/grayson-perry.jpg">
  <figcaption>I've moved out just as Walthamstow is becoming gentrified. My work is done.</figcaption>
</figure>
<cite>- Graysen Perry</cite>
```

I wouldn't expect the tail of the g and the y to hang down below the edge of the image.

Comment: Without the **actual** image this is hard to detect but my *guess* is that you need to set the image to `display:block`.

Comment: Oh...and they are called "descenders" not **tails**. ☺

Answer (score 0):

Make the image `display:block` and if you don't want the text to flow off the right of the image, make the figure `inline-block`

```css
.article-image,
figure {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}

figure {
  margin-block-start: 0em;
  margin-block-end: 0em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
}

cite {
  display:block;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

.aside-image {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img class="aside-image" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/300">
  <figcaption>I've moved out just as Walthamstow is becoming gentrified. My work is done.</figcaption>
</figure>
<cite>- Graysen Perry</cite>
```